# Microsoft CryptoAPI Book

Tags: windows, sockets, ssl, cryptoapi, mscapi

I need to write my own SSL socket (CSocket ansestor) with server side certificate validation using Microsoft CryptoAPI.

Can you tell me which book will help me (or any other user friendly source of information)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library [CSslSocket - SSL/TLS enabled CSocket](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslsocket.aspx)

and how it works [Creating a Secure Connection Using Schannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374782%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This pointer might also help, although it is not a book.
[CAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380255.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [SSL and TLS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615983) by [Eric Rescorla](http://www.rtfm.com/) (author of [ssldump](http://ssldump.sourceforge.net/)) to get a really good understanding of SSL.  It provides a great introduction to the protocol and the problems it solves, with the option to go as deep as you want into the details.

I would also strongly recommend *not* writing your own implementation unless you **really** have to.